# trying to add more table to mysqlcluster getting error ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 2137: The table 't_email_contacts' is full

Tags: mysql

Hi I am trying to insert tables to mysql cluster but after some time I get the following error, can you please suggest how to fix this.

ERROR 1114 (HY000) at line 2137: The table 't_email_contacts' is full

Hi Andrew, this is the result of ALL REPORT MEMORY

```
Node 2: Data usage is 0%(45 32K pages of total 98048)
Node 2: Index usage is 0%(408 8K pages of total 392224)
Node 3: Data usage is 0%(45 32K pages of total 98048)
Node 3: Index usage is 0%(408 8K pages of total 392224)
```

it shows 0%, but still I am getting table full error, thanks in advance.

1. df -H shows it is not full.
2. I am not using innodb for my table creation, it is ndb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few reasons for this.

1. The partition that holds the MySQL file is full. `df -H` will show if a partition is full.
2. If you are using innodb: see the `innodb_data_file_path` in your `my.cnf`. You might be exceeding the "max" amount. Example of this:

   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:512M

   You can up the 512 or remove the `:max:512m` totally for it to be "limitless".
3. You are adding an INDEX to a MEMORY table (obviously not the case but worth mentioning).

---

Regarding NDB Cluster:

4. [An NDB engine holds all data in RAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-mysql-cluster.html#qandaitem-B-10-1-13). From the link:

   > In MySQL 5.0, Cluster is in-memory only. This means that all table data (including indexes) is stored in RAM. Therefore, if your data takes up 1 GB of space and you want to replicate it once in the cluster, you need 2 GB of memory to do so (1 GB per replica). This is in addition to the memory required by the operating system and any applications running on the cluster computers

   If this is the cause you can do [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data-objects.html) but it will be a perfomance hit.
5. Check the values of `MaxNoOfConcurrentOperations` and `MaxNoOfConcurrentTransactions`. Set them to a value higher than the largest table in the cluster.
6. Check the log file for related messages (`ndb_2_trace.log`?). If it shows things like "Node 2: Data usage increased to 100%" you are running out of memory.

   - Index memory stores primary key indexes ONLY.
   - Data memory stores all the data + other indexes.
   - The memory you need per table is something like this: 
     ((size of a table) + (size of index)) * ( the number of records)
   - `IndexMemory` and `DataMemory` are the corresponding settings. If you exceed these you get this error.
7. The maximum number of attributes (columns and indexes) per table is limited to 128.

Comment: thanks for the response. 1. df -H shows it is not full. 2. I am not using innodb for my table creation, it is ndb

Comment: added to the question.

Comment: This is all I can come up with :D

Comment: I heard that we can use disk space insted of RAM, can you please tell me is there any such option

Comment: HI, there is no link in your comment. please share it again.

Comment: @ManojReddy yes there is.  "If this is the cause you can do this but it will be a perfomance hit." the "this" is a link.

Comment: I am very sorry to trouble you again, but 'this' has to be highlighted in your comment, but it is appearing as a normal text. Can you please paste the exact link in the comment.

Comment: @ManojReddy: Don't thank the poster!  ;-) If you like its answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the number to the left right now turning it into beautiful green....  **;-)**

Comment: I will defenetly accept the answer, but sorry the link is not available, I know the text 'this' take to the link, but it is not highlighted, it is showing just as a normal text.

Comment: But it is not showing for me, please paste the link without http atleast??

Comment: I accepted the answer, but please send me the link dont put http or www, it will come as normal comment please.

Comment: I don't think I can edit yoiur answer, can you please paste the link in the answer.

Comment: @ManojReddy: all links are rendered in red here. Once you hover over that red words you will see the link, and you can click on it or c & p it.

Comment: Hello everyone I know the links will be rednered in red, but they are just showing as normal text to me, I don’t have to fight for such a small thing for days.... Link is not getting highlited for me, it looks like a bug from askubuntu.com please send me the link in comment or I will look at any other forum for an answer.

Comment: Fine here it is: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-disk-data-objects.html